# Update specific data when someone edit his profile

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

When user update his email then update a specific row table.
I know how to take the new value of email, but I dont know how to use it in other row in different table.
table name: BIG
row name: secondName

I have this

```
function wpdocs_check_user_email_updated( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
    $old_user_email = $old_user_data->data->user_email;
 
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $new_user_email = $user->user_email;
 
    if ( $new_user_email !== $old_user_email ) {
        // I dont know how to do it
    }
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'wpdocs_check_user_email_updated', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WP predefine `wpdb::update` check the below code.

```
function wpdocs_check_user_email_updated( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $old_user_email = $old_user_data->data->user_email;
 
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $new_user_email = $user->user_email;
 
    if ( $new_user_email !== $old_user_email ) {
        
        $data  = array( 'your-column-name' => $new_user_email );
        $where = array( 'your-column-name' => $user_id );
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix . 'your_table', $data, $where );

    }
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'wpdocs_check_user_email_updated', 10, 2 );
```

USEFUL LINKS

- [wpdb::update](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/)

Comment: Thx you! Its not necessary put the matched column between the tables?

Comment: Yes, it's necessary that's why we `$where = array( 'your-column-name' => $user_id );` added this.

Comment: I mean, the first table (wordpress) is taking 'ID' column with $user_id, but the new table is using 'externalId' column to store the user id. Its this an issue? Oh you answered before, thx man